# Get product collection in Magento, filtered by Category & Custom Attribute Value

Tags: magento

I am creating magento API so now I need to get product collection from category id and catalog attribute id.

for ex :
I have category with name test and id is 1 . Also I have set attribute `color` (from `catalog->attributes->manage attributes`) and I have set values for this color attribute like `white` , `blue` , `black`.

now I add few product and it's category is test (id=1) and color attribute is set `white`.

My Question is : 
Now I want to get product collection for whom category id is `1` and color is `white`.

How can I get this collection.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
// load category object by category ID
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1);

// get product collection, filter it by category, 
// add the color attribute to select to be able to filter using it later
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                       ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                       ->addAttributeToSelect('color')
                       ->addFieldToFilter(array(
                           array('attribute'=>'color','eq'=>'white'),
                       ));
```

More info check

[How to get products from a particular category in magento ecommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454462/how-to-get-products-from-a-particular-category-in-magento-ecommerce)

[Magento - Retrieve products with a specific attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/get-product-collection-from-a-category-id

Comment: if I want to filter with color and size then  ->addAttributeToSelect(array('color','size') does work or not? and if not then what is the correct way to get collection by color and size.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if that is possible or no but as far as i know and tried myself, `addAttributeToSelect()` is used to add attributes to the `select` part of the query, which allows you to later on filter using it.

Comment: In a very simple way (table/column names are not true), assume that this is the original query `SELECT id, sku FROM products`, but we want to filter using attribute `color` and value `white`, so we have to tell Magento to add the attribute `color` to the query, which changes it to `SELECT id, sku, color FROM products`, then we want to tell Magento to filter for specific value for `color`, which changes the query to `SELECT id, sku, color FROM products WHERE color = 'white'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $attributeCode = 'Your_Attribute_Code';
    $attributeOption = 'Attribute_Option';
    $attributeDetails = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
    $options = $attributeDetails->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    $selectedOptionId = false;

    foreach ($options as $option){
        if ($option['label'] == $attributeOption) {
            $selectedOptionId = $option['value'];
        }
    }

    if ($selectedOptionId) {
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('eq' => $selectedOptionId));

        foreach($products as $product){
            echo $product->getId();
            echo $product->getName();
        }
    }
?>
```