# Is there a way to add a section of the main nav in the sidebar?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, sidebar

We have a category **"products"** in our main nav and under this category is a **dropdown** menu.

We would like to only add the dropdown part of the "products" category from the main nav in the **sidebar**.

This code (tnx to https://inchoo.net/magento/custom-category-menu-navigation-in-magento/) got it working. But it also gives the other links in the main navigation.

**How can I edit this code that it is only showing 1 category by it's ID?**

```
<ul>
<?php
    $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
    $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
    Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';
    foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
?>
        <li>
            <strong><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></strong>
            <?php $categoryChildren = $_category->getChildren(); ?>
            <?php if($categoryChildren->count()) : ?>
                <ul>

                    <?php foreach($categoryChildren as $_categoryChild) : ?>
                        <?php $_categoryChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryChild->getId());?>
                        <?php $categoryGrandchildren=$_categoryChild->getChildren(); ?>
                        <li>
                            <?php
                                $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                echo '&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryChildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryChild->getName() . '(' . $_categoryChildModel->getProductCollection()->count() . ')</a>';
                            ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php if($categoryGrandchildren->count()) : ?>
                            <?php foreach($categoryGrandchildren as $_categoryGrandchild) : ?>
                                <?php $_categoryGrandchildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryGrandchild->getId());?>
                                <li>
                                    <?php
                                        $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                        echo '&emsp;&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryGrandchild->getName() . '(' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getProductCount() . ')</a>';
                                    ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
        $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
        $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
        Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';
        foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
    ?>
         <?php if($_category->getId() == 123) : ?>
            <li>
                <strong><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></strong>
                <?php $categoryChildren = $_category->getChildren(); ?>
                <?php if($categoryChildren->count()) : ?>
                    <ul>

                        <?php foreach($categoryChildren as $_categoryChild) : ?>
                            <?php $_categoryChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryChild->getId());?>
                            <?php $categoryGrandchildren=$_categoryChild->getChildren(); ?>
                            <li>
                                <?php
                                    $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                    echo '&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryChildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryChild->getName() . '(' . $_categoryChildModel->getProductCollection()->count() . ')</a>';
                                ?>
                            </li>
                            <?php if($categoryGrandchildren->count()) : ?>
                                <?php foreach($categoryGrandchildren as $_categoryGrandchild) : ?>
                                    <?php $_categoryGrandchildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryGrandchild->getId());?>
                                    <li>
                                        <?php
                                            $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                            echo '&emsp;&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryGrandchild->getName() . '(' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getProductCount() . ')</a>';
                                        ?>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
       <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

Following part I believe will help: 123 is the category ID,  change this to yours.

```
<?php if($_category->getId() == 123) : ?>
```

Comment: Actually it is better to not load all the categories and then loop them, I think you can also get just the required category, I could explain but if this is good enough just use an if statement:)

Comment: please do explain. I tried to add your code, it got it working. but if there is e better way... :D

Comment: Well I looked into it and probably this is a better way than I thought. To load a single category you could use xml like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454462/how-to-get-products-from-a-particular-category-in-magento-ecommerce . But if it works and page load is good I wouldn't worry :)

Comment: I will leave it this way, it's working. Thanks for your help and time!