# How to select the products that have same name and same categories in a Magento collection

Tags: magento

How can I create a collection to get all products with the same name (grouped by name) and the  same category (grouped by category) in the same collection ??

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Are you saying you want a collection of products that have duplicate name/category information?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand clearly what you want. You can group products by name using groupByAttribute method:

```
$_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_collection->groupByAttribute('name');
```

But grouping by category is not that simple, since one product can be in more categories. So I am not sure if it is possible, you will probably have to write some checking script logic.

---

But maybe, you want just get products by name with

```
$_collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', 'My product name')
```

And get products by category: [Magento products by categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272818/magento-products-by-categories)

---

Read more about collections in Magento:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: Thank you a lot, my problem is with the grouping by categories, I have tried to make a join with the table eav_attribute, and the column ´category_ids´ but, I get always ‘e.category_ids’ in ‘where clause’.... Any more help ?