# Magento: show products from a specific category in the footer

Tags: magento

I'm building a "Product of the Month" block for the footer. It should load a category's products and display the first one.

This is my template file `custom/featured-product.phtml`:

```
<?php $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>

<div class="featured-product">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Product of the Month') ?></h2>

    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <div class="item">
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>

            <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a>

            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        // Note: Exit after first product.
        break;
        ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

It's just a simplified version of Magento's product list template: `catalog/product/list.phtml`

## WORKING

When embedding the block in a CMS Page, it works fine. Example:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="13" template="custom/featured-product.phtml" }}
```

## NOT WORKING

When embedding the block via `local.xml`, it fails. The correct markup is returned but the specified category is not loaded. Instead a *random* (I don't how they're selected) set of products is loaded.

My code in `local.xml`:

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="custom.featuredProduct" as="product_of_the_month" category_id="13" template="custom/featured-product.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

For completeness, I am rendering the block explicitly in `page/html/footer.phtml` like so:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_of_the_month') ?>
```

## Any ideas?

My best guess is my `local.xml` is incorrect. Is there a parent block I need to load?

## [Updates]

My original code crashes the product page. The workaround is *not* basing the code so heavily on the Magento core file: `catalog/product/list.phtml`. Specifically avoiding this line:

```
<?php $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>
```

## [Solution]

A working version with examples for use in CMS Pages and LayoutXML is included here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288000/1497746

Comment: `local.xml` - where is this file located? (full path)

Comment: @FlorinelChis — This isn't an issue with theme fallback hierarchy. It's the normal place for a custom package: /app/design/frontend/custom/custom/layout/local.xml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a working solution using Alan Storm's advice.

**/template/custom/featured-product.phtml**

```
<?php
$_categoryId = $this->getCategoryId();

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
?>

<div class="featured-product">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__( $this->getLabel() ); ?></h2>

    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <div class="item">
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>

            <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a>

            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        // Note: Exit after first product.
        break;
        ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

In short, the collection is manually generated rather than receiving a collection (as my initial attempt did):

```
<?php $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count(); ?>
```

## Using in a CMS Page:

```
{{block type="core/template" category_id="13" label="Product of the Month" template="custom/featured-product.phtml" }}
```

## Using in a template:

**/layout/local.xml**

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom.featuredProduct" as="featured_product" template="custom/featured-product.phtml">
            <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>13</value></action>
            <action method="setData"><key>label</key><value>Product of the Month</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

**/template/page/html/footer.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('featured_product') ?>
```

## Helpful resources:

How to get a product collection:

- http://overlycaffeinated.com/2011/02/get-all-sale-products-from-a-category-in-magento/
- [Magento products by categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272818/magento-products-by-categories)

Using magic getters/setters:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008251/1497746
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006374/1497746
- http://www.magestore.com/blog/2012/02/29/magento-cetificate-pass-variables-from-layout-to-block/

Comment: Noticed that `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>` doesn't seem to render.

Comment: did you find a solution to rendering the price? @brendan-falkowski

Answer (score 5):

First, I've had random problems over the years using layout update xml attribute nodes to set values on blocks (other than `template`, `as`, `name`, `type`, or `class`, so trying something like this

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="custom.featuredProduct" as="product_of_the_month" template="custom/featured-product.phtml">
            <action method="setCategoryId"><id>13</id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

or this

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="custom.featuredProduct" as="product_of_the_month" template="custom/featured-product.phtml">
            <action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>13</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

may help, and would be my first step.

After that, I'd go look at the block code that's loading the collection

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    ...
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }        
    ...
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                }
            }
            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }                
}
```

The `getLoadedProductCollection` method wraps a call to `_getProductCollection`, and `_getProductCollection` is where the collection is actually loaded.

So, some temporary debugging code in

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    var_dump($this->getCategoryId());
    Mage::Log(__METHOD__);
    Mage::Log($this->getCategoryId());
}
```

Can help ensure your category id is making it from the layout update XML to the block.

However, if you look a little deeper at `_getProductCollection`, you'll notice that there's a few conditions where it **resets** the category ID.

```
if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
    $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
}
...
if (Mage::registry('product')) {
    // get collection of categories this product is associated with
    $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
        ->setPage(1, 1)
        ->load();
    // if the product is associated with any category
    if ($categories->count()) {
        // show products from this category
        $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
    }
}
...
```

Is some other piece of Magento code has set the `show_root_category` property, or you're on a page where there's a product object in the registry, Magento will override your category id.

Making things even more complicated, once the collection is loaded it's set on a protected property

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
```

that has no public getter method.

The ways to proceed here are myriad.  If it were me I'd consider one of the following

1. Using a custom block class that extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and has a method for resetting the category on a collection or loading a new collection
2. Loading the collection myself, without relying on the code in `product/list`

Comment: The `<action method="setCategoryId"><id>13</id></action>` method and `<action method="setData"><key>category_id</key><value>13</value></action>` method work on *CMS Pages* and *Catalog View*. An exception is thrown on *Product View*. Investigating...

Comment: Magento *does* appear to override the collection on *Product View* causing an exception I don't know how to trace, so I moved onto your final two suggestions. #2 worked for me. Will post as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully recreated the problem under Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

First I created a local.xml with this content:

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="custom.featuredProduct" as="product_of_the_month" category_id="13" template="custom/featured-product.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

I figured out, that some wrapping XML elements are missing and added some extra lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="custom.featuredProduct" as="product_of_the_month" category_id="13" template="custom/featured-product.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

After adding the needed XML elements it worked.

Comment: — Good idea, but my `local.xml` includes these also. I only posted the abridged, relevant code.

Comment: My be you have some special case. Just for the record: I tested it only for home page. Also I created dummy theme where put the local.xml  and custom/featured-product.phtml No extensions installed. Products sample data was used and I only changed the category id.

Comment: Did it load the right product collection from the specified category?