# magento show number of products in the category?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am pretty newbie to the magento. I want to show the number of products in the categories in the left sidebar just like

- Product-1 (21)
- Product-2 (11)
- Product-3 (16)
- Product-4 (68)

  So for showing all the products with category and its sub category I made my `left_nav.phtml` file which is inside the folder location `app/design/frontend/my-theme/default/template/catalog/navigation/` something like [this](http://pastebin.com/p7c1QuE5)

Now it is showing all the categories and sub categories. But I want all the category and subcategory should show the numbers of product in the respective category with it. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be appreciable.

Comment: This question is more or less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272818/magento-products-by-categories the difference being that you should call $products->count() to get the count.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to display it in view.phtml you already have the current category object there so you can use $_category->getId()

```
$products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())
 ->getProductCount();

echo($products_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addCategoryFilter($mycategory);

echo "(".count($collection).")";
```

Warning : $mycategory have to be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Category, not an id.

Regards,